# Cloudformation EC2 instance add External DNS and IP to .conf file on init

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am creating a cloud formation file that sets up an EC2 instance and installs a some applications etc on it. It then also installs squid which is being used to add password protection from the web.

The issue i'm having is the config file needs to be setup with the external ip and public dns address when the instance is setup. Unfortunately these don't exist until the EC2 instance is initialised and if i try to refer to this value in the userData of the instance in the cloud-formation script i get a circular reference error.

Does anyone know how i can get the cloudformation script to update this conf after the instance has been created and the public IP and DNS addresses assigned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this information from the [metadata server](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) at http://169.254.169.254 that's available on every EC2 instance.

To get the public IP use:

```
curl -f http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4
```

To get the public domain use:

```
curl -f http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname
```

Use those in your userdata script.